# Forms Authentication equivalent for the Membership API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

My website's administration portal is only accessed by a single user, and it is for this reason that I  chose to use basic forms authentication -

```
public bool Authenticate(string username, string password)
{
    var authenticated = FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(username, password);
    if (authenticated)
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, false);
    return authenticated;
}
...
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/login" timeout="2880">
    <credentials passwordFormat="SHA1">
      <user name="admin" password="ABC.." />
    </credentials>
  </forms>
</authentication>
```

Recently I learned that the `FormsAuthentication.Authenticate` method has been deprecated and that I should use the membership API instead.

What is the membership API equivalent for `FormsAuthentication.Authenticate` that will allow me to store credentials the in web.config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is one. I think storing credentials in web.config is the reason the API is obsolete. In addition there is a newer API than Membership - ASP.NET Identity. If you are going to rewrite your authentication code with newer API better go for ASP.NET Identity. However if your use case is really one user and you are not really worried about security you may just leave it be.